# How to construct a CRON expression from a user entry form?

Tags: .net, quartz.net

I need to construct a Cron expression based on some user entry in a form. The user would choose some values such as below and they will be any combination based on the values chosen from some pre-configured dropdowns.
How can I construct Cron expression to use Cronos.Net library and calculate the next occurence? Thank you!

Once a week, Fridays, 10:00 am
Once a day, 2:00 pm

Comment: https://github.com/HangfireIO/Cronos

Comment: https://medium.com/@tushar0618/cron-expression-tutorial-721d85e4c2a7

Comment: Thank you for the links. It looks like we need to format the CRON expression based on the schedule chosen from user entry.